# Wordpress: The bootstrap cache file gets corrupted every few weeks

Tags: wordpress

Good Morning!

I have a Wordpress site with a cherry template!

The design of the website fits, but after a few days or weeks, the slider and the menu do not work, the positions and colors do not fit either - as if individual CSS files were missing. If I now delete the cache files style.less.cache and bootstrap.less.cache everything works again.

Before deleting the files are empty.

Does anyone have a similar problem? 
I've been looking for a solution forever :-)

best regards
Horst

.htaccess File:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: which cache plugin you are using?

Comment: Hello! At first, I did not use one. Now I have tried Super Cache, but still, have the same problem

Comment: The cache file only contains "N;"

Comment: can you share me the site url?

Comment: Site not opening.

Comment: OK, that was a wrong classification by Avast. According to Avast, the issue should be resolved in the next few hours

Comment: still issue is there?

Comment: No, I deleted the cache files and everything works again. But I have no idea why this problem occurs. Sometimes it appears after 2 days. Sometimes after a month. But I can not check every page every day :-D If the problem occurs, the two cache files are empty, but are used. It looks like no css is deposited. I still have the .less files on the server. Should they be deleted?

Comment: check your htacess file

Comment: The .htaccess file looks good in my opinion?

Comment: yes. seems its correct.